# Fingerprint SDK

Tags: c#, .net, fingerprint

I am using fingerprint reader UFP20.The SDK providing 2 DLL files (WIS_API.dll,WisCmos2.dll). Unfortunately they not provide c# demo code. I could connect the device and test the device. Its working perfectly.

Problem : 
           I can't capture finger print even capture initialize function working perfectly.
I got error when i calling WIS_Capture() function. Error - "This function trying to access protected memory area, that may damage the system"

For more details about the function :-

**WIS_Capture**

```
Synopsis
         int WINAPI WIS_Capture( HANDLE hInit, int *rCount )
Parameter
        hInit        The handle returned by WIS_InitDriver()
        rCount       A value used internally by the function. The developer MUST 
                     initial this value to 0 before use.

Description :
     To snap a fingerprint from the fingerprint device to the main memory by a
     fingerprint image quality control process. The fingerprint quality control 
     cycle needs several frames of images and will continuously return the 
     status of the fingerprint after each frame of image captured.
```

Please help me to avoid this error.

Answer (score 0):

"This function trying to access protected memory area, that may damage the system"

this sounds similar to the error you get when you call unmanaged code from managed code.

According to [THIS](http://74.125.93.132/search?q=cache%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.experts-exchange.com%2FProgramming%2FEditors_IDEs%2FC_CPP_CS%2FQ_23968549.html&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) (you need to scroll all the way down to see the answers) you may need to add those dll's to your project solution using References -> Com.This will create a managed code wrapper so you can use them in your code.

Comment: Thanks for u r quick reply. But I can't add my dll's to reference. It shows an error "The file u selected not a valid assembly or COM component" when I adding reference. The dll's providing the SDK. I know only abt the functions.Please give me another solution to solve this prob.

Comment: @avatarofchronos, we can not all the dll files under References->com, only COM dll files can be added there.

Answer (score 0):

My friend, Avatar is right, you must call the unmanaged dll functions with some code like this:

```
namespace SDK_DLL_NS
   {
      internal class SDK_DLL
         {
            [DllImport("../../../SDK/SDK.dll")]
            public static extern unsafe int SDK_AMethod(int devHandle, IntPtr buf, int length);
            public const int MAX_LEN = 12345;  
.....
    }
}
```

Now, this is just the interfacing part of the job, the .NET virtual machine memory by definition is not fixed and this is what the dll expects, fortunately we have the System.Runtime.InteropServices namespaces for help with its GCHandle struct which provides a way to access a managed object from unmanaged code. So i think the code could be something like this, we need to allocate some memory "a la native code":

```
SDKdllBuffer = new byte[SDK_DLL.MAX_LEN];
pinnedBuffer = GCHandle.Alloc(SDKdllBuffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);

unsafe
     {
        SDK_DLL.SDK_AMethod(handle, pinnedBuffer.AddrOfPinnedObject(),MAX_LEN);
}
```

Hope this give you a idea. Good Luck.
Juan